# How to enable button focus on touchStart?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, tss

I have created a button, I need some response from button like, on touch of the button, the button focus should enable like change in background color. How can I do that?

My code is, 
**View:**

```
<Button class="button" id="proceedButton" onClick="openQuestionnaire">Proceed</Button>
```

**Style:**

```
".button":{
    width: '50%',
    top: '25dp',
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#808080',  
    backgroundGradient: {
        type: "linear",
        startPoint: { x: "0%", y:"0%"},
        endPoint:   { x: "0%", y:"100%"},
        colors: [
            { color: "#4F94CD", offset: 0.0 },
            { color: "#4F94CD", offset: 1.0 }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$.proceedButton.addEventListener('touchstart', function() { 
    $.proceedButton.isFocused = true;
  });  

  $.proceedButton.addEventListener('touchend', function() { 
     $.proceedButton.isFocused = false;
  });
```

The above code is not working. Just I need to slight chage in background color while touch of the button.

Any solution!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @CodeForFun mentioned you can use `backgroundSelectedColor` property of button.

Also following are all the states which can be used by a button in Titanium.

- Disabled : [backgroundDisabledImage](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundDisabledImage) and [backgroundDisabledColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundDisabledImage)
- Normal : [backgroundImage](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundImage) and [backgroundColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundColor)
- Focus : [backgroundFocusedImage](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundFocusedImage) and [backgroundFocusedColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundFocusedColor)
- Selected : [backgroundSelectedImage](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundSelectedImage) and [backgroundSelectedColor](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundSelectedColor)

Hope this would be helpful.

**Edit :** An example of usage:

*View :*

```
<Button class="button" >Proceed</Button>
```

*TSS :*

```
".button":{
width: '50%',
top: '25dp',
backgroundSelectedColor : "#4F94CD" //usage
}
```

Comment: Where can I use backgroundSelectedColor property?

Answer (score 2):

Use this property and pass colour code

```
backgroundSelectedColor : "RED"
```

focusable must be true for normal views.
for more you can refer this http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundSelectedColor

I hope it may help you,

Comment: Where can I use this property?

Comment: on button property add this.

Comment: remove touch start and touch end event listner from controller, and just add property of backgroundSelectedColor : "RED" .

Comment: @CodeForFun Sorry didnt see that you have mentioned the right answer already.

Answer (score 2):

Alloy xml would be like this

`<Button class="button" id="proceedButton" onClick="openQuestionnaire">Proceed</Button>`

Then the button property would be like this

```
".button":{
 width: '50%',
 top: '25dp',
 borderRadius: 8,
 borderWidth: 1,
 borderColor: '#808080',
 backgroundSelectedColor : "red",
 backgroundSelectedImage : "/my_image.png",
 backgroundGradient: {
    type: "linear",
    startPoint: { x: "0%", y:"0%"},
    endPoint:   { x: "0%", y:"100%"},
    colors: [
        { color: "#4F94CD", offset: 0.0 },
        { color: "#4F94CD", offset: 1.0 }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can set your selected image or background color on touch focus. 
You wont need the controller code you have written in the controller.
Also for some object you can also have selectedColor. 
You can also set backgroundFocusedImage,